# jquery function on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a quicker way of doing this:

```
function star1() {  myFunction();jQuery('.star-position1').animate({"opacity":opacity},timeIn,function() { star1(); }); }
function star2() {  myFunction();jQuery('.star-position2').animate({"opacity":opacity},timeIn,function() { star2(); }); }
```

and so on..

I'm then init these functions with

```
star1();
star2();
```

etc..

great if I could pass a number the number of stars I have and it generates the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function star(num){
  myFunction();
  jQuery('.star-position' + num).animate({"opacity":opacity},timeIn,function() { 
    star(num); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor functions with passing a number as an argument to a single function:

```
function star(n) {
    myFunction();
    $('.star-position' + n).animate({
        opacity: opacity
    }, timeIn, function() {
        star(n);
    });
}

star(1);
star(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could do this:

```
function star(id) { 
    myFunction();
    jQuery('.star-position'+id).animate(
        {"opacity":opacity},
        timeIn,
        function() { 
            star(id); 
        });
}
```

And then call:

```
star(1);
star(2);
```

You can pass in `id` as an integer and concatenate it with `'.star-position'` since JavaScript doesn't care about variable types (most of the time).